# "npm start" fail in react tutorial

Tags: reactjs

so I'm trying to learn how to use React using the tutorial from the following website: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

I followed all the instructions for the setup of the local development environment, but when I try to run "npm start" I face the following error.

> my-app@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

Could not find a required file.
Name: index.js

Searched in: C:\Users\myname\my-app\src

I'm using vs code to implement this. Any idea why it's not working and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you skipped this part?

```
Add a file named index.css in the src/ folder with this CSS code.
Add a file named index.js in the src/ folder with this JS code.
Add these three lines to the top of index.js in the src/ folder:
```

Comment: Not sure what went wrong, I went back and redid everything again and now its working. Thank you though!